# How to resize the auto suggestion menu width in Ace editor

Tags: css, ace-editor, ui-ace

I am working on project which needs multiple ace editor instances running, all with auto completion feature enabled

I want increase the width of suggestion window presented by one particular alone. Changing the width using the below class works, but it applies for all the error instance, which i don't need.

```
div.ace_editor.ace_autocomplete {
   width: 40%
}
```

Is there a way where i can specifically target one particular ace editor instance alone?

Answer (score 3):

Autocompleters for each editor do not have any specific classes, so you need to modify them by javascript, either adding class or style

```
if (!editor.completer) {
   // make sure completer is initialized
   editor.execCommand("startAutocomplete")
   editor.completer.detach()
}
editor.completer.popup.container.style.width="40%"
editor.completer.popup.container.classList.add("foo")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could even use resize() to change the width of the specific editors instance:

```
var popup = editor.completer.popup; 
popup.container.style.width="100px"; 
popup.resize();
```